# How to Bluetooth Low Energy Server connect?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing Bluetooth 4.0.

I want to receive data when Tag(Server) send data.

Tag is not save data when send the data.

I hope use below source

```
private BluetoothGattServerCallback mGattServerCallbacks = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset,
            byte[] value) {
}

mGattServerCallbacks conntect mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, mGattServerCallbacks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but it sounds to me like what you want is GATT server notification or indication [1]. If you connect to a device (this Tag server) and you want to receive data from this device when it has data to send, then what you do is indicate (acknowledge send) or notify (unacknowledged) this data.

From your Android application you enable notification for a given characteristics on the connected device and every time that characteristic is changed you get the data pushed to you.

This would typically be used for a temperature service. Whenever the measured temperature on the sensor changes a notification is sent out to the connected device(s) with the new value.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, boolean)